# Nullpointer exception in Spring Java Project with Swing GUI

Tags: java, spring, swing, nullpointerexception

Hell Everyone,
I am new to spring, java programming. I have created a java program which is supposed to access the database on the action of click, but I do not know why I am getting nullpointer exception because all the object is being set properly.

Swing Code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.ui;

import com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.model.TypeCategory;
import com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.model.TypeCategoryJDBCTemplate;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;

/**
 *
 * @author Ashish Tyagi
 */
public class ApplicationWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    TypeCategoryJDBCTemplate typeCategoryJDBCtemplate;

    /**
     * Creates new form ApplicationWindow
     */

    public void setTypeCategoryJDBCtemplate(TypeCategoryJDBCTemplate typeCategoryJDBCtemplate) {
        this.typeCategoryJDBCtemplate = typeCategoryJDBCtemplate;
        System.err.println("setter in the application window "+this.typeCategoryJDBCtemplate);
    }


    public ApplicationWindow() {
        initComponents();
        addRadioButtonInGroup();
        setTitle("Taxonomy Updator");
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        buttonGroup = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        infoLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        searchButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        beginButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        endButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        exactButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        anywhereButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        closeButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        updateAllButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        updateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        infoLabel.setText("Please enter the text you wants to search");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 3;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(11, 10, 0, 0);
        getContentPane().add(infoLabel, gridBagConstraints);

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 10;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 279;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(6, 10, 0, 0);
        getContentPane().add(jTextField1, gridBagConstraints);

        searchButton.setText("Search");
        searchButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                searchButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 19;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 25;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 17;
        gridBagConstraints.ipady = -3;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(6, 6, 0, 10);
        getContentPane().add(searchButton, gridBagConstraints);

        beginButton.setText("Begin with");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 10, 0, 0);
        getContentPane().add(beginButton, gridBagConstraints);

        endButton.setText("End with");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 0, 0, 0);
        getContentPane().add(endButton, gridBagConstraints);

        exactButton.setText("Exact Match");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 5;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 0, 0, 0);
        getContentPane().add(exactButton, gridBagConstraints);

        anywhereButton.setText("Anywhere");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 9;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 11;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 0, 0, 0);
        getContentPane().add(anywhereButton, gridBagConstraints);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 3;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 44;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 351;
        gridBagConstraints.ipady = 60;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 10, 0, 10);
        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, gridBagConstraints);

        closeButton.setText("Close");
        closeButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                closeButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 43;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(175, 6, 0, 10);
        getContentPane().add(closeButton, gridBagConstraints);

        updateAllButton.setText("Update All");
        updateAllButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                updateAllButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 6;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 24;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(175, 6, 0, 0);
        getContentPane().add(updateAllButton, gridBagConstraints);

        updateButton.setText("Update");
        updateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                updateButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(175, 8, 0, 0);
        getContentPane().add(updateButton, gridBagConstraints);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

private void searchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String text = jTextField1.getText();
    java.util.List<TypeCategory> records = this.typeCategoryJDBCtemplate.listTypeCategory(text);
    for(TypeCategory value:records)
    System.out.println(value.getDescription()+"  "+value.getTaxonomydescription());
}                                            


    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void updateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                            

    private void updateAllButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                               

    private void closeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        this.dispose();
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public void start() {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ApplicationWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ApplicationWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ApplicationWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ApplicationWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ApplicationWindow().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton anywhereButton;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton beginButton;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup;
    private javax.swing.JButton closeButton;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton endButton;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton exactButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel infoLabel;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JButton searchButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton updateAllButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton updateButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private void addRadioButtonInGroup() {
        buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        buttonGroup.add(beginButton);
        buttonGroup.add(endButton);
        buttonGroup.add(exactButton);
        buttonGroup.add(anywhereButton);
    }
}
```

Main File:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate;
import com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.model.TypeCategoryJDBCTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.ui.ApplicationWindow;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

/**
 *
 * @author Ashish Tyagi
 */
public class TaxonomyUpdater {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Config.xml");
        ApplicationWindow window= (ApplicationWindow) context.getBean("applicationWindow");
        window.start();
//        TypeCategoryJDBCTemplate typecategoryJDBCTemplate = (TypeCategoryJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("typeCategoryJDBCTemplate");
//        window.setTypeCategoryJDBCtemplate(typecategoryJDBCTemplate);
//        List<TypeCategory> records=typecategoryJDBCTemplate.listTypeCategory("Q2%");
//        for(TypeCategory value:records)
//            System.out.println(value.getTypecatind()+"  "+value.getDescription()+" "+value.getTaxonomydescription());
    }

}
```

Spring-Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:db2://sample.sample.com:3798/sampledb"/>
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="typeCategoryJDBCTemplate" class="com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.model.TypeCategoryJDBCTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="applicationWindow" class="com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.ui.ApplicationWindow">
        <property name="typeCategoryJDBCtemplate" ref="typeCategoryJDBCTemplate" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Logs which is verifying that object is being created but still null pointer exception.

```
Mar 17, 2013 12:24:51 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
Inside the setDataSoureorg.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@4389b7
setter in the application window com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.model.TypeCategoryJDBCTemplate@18c6fd4
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.ui.ApplicationWindow.searchButtonActionPerformed(ApplicationWindow.java:207)
    at com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.ui.ApplicationWindow.access$100(ApplicationWindow.java:15)
    at com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.ui.ApplicationWindow$2.actionPerformed(ApplicationWindow.java:88)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: where exactly are you getting the null pointer exception?  stack trace?

Comment: i am not going to dig through all this stuff trying to figure out where the NPE is. put the stacktrace in the question.

Comment: @bchurchill I have updated the question with NPE stack trace, thanks for looking

Comment: @NathanHughes I have updated the question with NPE, thanks for looking

Comment: and, what line exactly corresponds to 207 in ApplicationWindow.java?  What have you done so far to debug?

Comment: @bchurchill:     java.util.List<TypeCategory> records = this.typeCategoryJDBCtemplate.listTypeCategory(text); this is line 207 and I have print the value of object which is properly created, you can see in the log itself.

Comment: I noticed that you have a setter method, but not a getter method for TypeCategoryJDBCTemplate. Please can you add this method in and try again? Also please stay consistent with your camel case declaration of the variable "typeCategoryJDBCtemplate" as this can be sensitive. Therefore please rename this to typeCategoryJDBCTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for looking into it, but I have found the problem in my code which was to create the window in ApplicatoinWindow -> start() method. It was creating the object and returning the control.

```
 /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ApplicationWindow().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

I changed it to

```
        /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```